# Two show result that contains difference between two table from different database

Tags: sql-server

I have two table from two database one is local another one is live in server so need to find what all difference are in two table with both table columns as shown in Image.

I need result as in below Image so is their any other way to find?

When am doing for this below query it is loading but unable to produce result and when i reduce the conditions it is producing the results but i need proper result for whole query.

```
select DISTINCT 
    tu.ModuleID, 
    tu.AllowAdd, 
    tu.AllowEdit, 
    tu.AllowDelete, 
    tu.AllowSupervision,
    tt.ModuleID,
    tt.AllowAdd,
    tt.AllowEdit,
    tt.AllowDelete,
    tt.AllowSupervision
from 
    t_UserModule tu,
    [smf5.0_check].dbo.t_usermodule tt
where 
    tu.ModuleID = tt.ModuleID
    and tu.OperatorID = tt.OperatorID
    and tu.AllowAdd <> tt.AllowAdd
    or tu.AllowEdit <> tt.AllowEdit
    or tu.AllowDelete <> tt.AllowDelete
    or tu.AllowSupervision <> tt.AllowSupervision
```

[image]

Comment: can any of the columns contain null values, how many rows will the table contain ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk:No null columns. The produces result contain 400 lines result.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: What you mean by "Don't forget to accept an answer"? I said query executed thanks for your info.

Comment: there is a small checkbox next to the score

Comment: do you want each row twice just reversed like in your example ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: ok i did.. i forgot to do that.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: no it is not twice just check , it is for different operator , in query i did not selected the operator..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I understand there were some performance issues with my old answer. Here is a new answer this can handle null values:

```
SELECT
    t1.ModuleID, 
    t1.AllowAdd, 
    t1.AllowEdit, 
    t1.AllowDelete, 
    t1.AllowSupervision,
    t2.ModuleID,
    t2.AllowAdd,
    t2.AllowEdit,
    t2.AllowDelete,
    t2.AllowSupervision
FROM
    t_UserModule t1
JOIN 
    [smf5.0_check].dbo.t_usermodule t2
ON
    t1.ModuleID = t1.ModuleID and
    t2.OperatorID = t2.OperatorID
WHERE not exists
  (SELECT
     t1.AllowAdd, 
     t1.AllowEdit,
     t1.AllowDelete,
     t1.AllowSupervision
   INTERSECT
   SELECT
     t2.AllowAdd, 
     t2.AllowEdit,
     t2.AllowDelete,
     t2.AllowSupervision)
```

Comment: change t1 alias to t2 in the first part of union. Anyway why to do thing so complex when you can use FULL JOIN?

Comment: @sidux because the full join doesn't show data from both tables as the question requests.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk : Thanks for your info , me little bit confuse about your code, am very basic to sql. You using t2.Allow id but not mentioned from which table so it showing error.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk :  could you please review your query ?

Comment: he is making a row from both tables a+b in the first query. In the second he adds rows for b+a. In the last query he removes all the queries where a+b <> a+a or b+a<>a+a. So that means that all the records must match.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk:Same thing happening , its just loading unable to produce result.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: ya query is correct sorry for inconvenience , Its takes 12.36 mint. Finaly excuted thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `WHERE` clause. You need to group the `ORs`.

```
WHERE
    tu.ModuleID = tt.ModuleID
    and tu.OperatorID = tt.OperatorID
    and (
        tu.AllowAdd <> tt.AllowAdd
        or tu.AllowEdit <> tt.AllowEdit
        or tu.AllowDelete <> tt.AllowDelete
        or tu.AllowSupervision <> tt.AllowSupervision
    )
```

Alternatively, you can write your query like this:

```
SELECT 
    tu.ModuleID, 
    tu.AllowAdd, 
    tu.AllowEdit, 
    tu.AllowDelete, 
    tu.AllowSupervision,
    tt.ModuleID,
    tt.AllowAdd,
    tt.AllowEdit,
    tt.AllowDelete,
    tt.AllowSupervision
FROM t_UserModule tu
INNER JOIN [smf5.0_check].dbo.t_usermodule tt
    ON tu.ModuleID = tt.ModuleID
    AND tu.OperatorID = tt.OperatorID
WHERE    
    tu.AllowAdd <> tt.AllowAdd
    OR tu.AllowEdit <> tt.AllowEdit
    OR tu.AllowDelete <> tt.AllowDelete
    OR tu.AllowSupervision <> tt.AllowSupervision
```

Comment: this query will return records if only there are ModuleID and OperatorId in both tables. In case there are records with ModuleID+OperatorID that exists in only 1 table then it will return nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM    t_UserModule tu 
FULL JOIN [smf5.0_check].dbo.t_usermodule tt
ON   tu.ModuleID = tt.ModuleID
        AND tu.OperatorID = tt.OperatorID
        AND tu.AllowAdd = tt.AllowAdd
        AND tu.AllowEdit = tt.AllowEdit
        AND tu.AllowDelete = tt.AllowDelete
        AND tu.AllowSupervision = tt.AllowSupervision
WHERE     tu.ModuleID IS NULL OR  tt.ModuleID     IS NULL
```

if there are NULLable columns then you need to do something like `COALESCE(tu.AllowAdd,-1) = COALESCE(tt.AllowAdd,-1)` in join conditions